Yocto Producer and User Issues
I am trying to build 2 recipes. dbc-creator and mainapplication. mainapplication depends on dbc-creator and requires that some files be in place and usable.
So in the dbc-creator recipe I have
S = "${WORKDIR}/git/DBC_Creator"

inherit python3native

DEPENDS += "python3 python3-pip-native"

do_compile() {
    echo "Installing Requirements..."
    cd ${S}
    ${STAGING_BINDIR_NATIVE}/pip3 install -r requirements.txt
    echo "Requirements DONE..."
    python3 dbc_creator.py
}

do_install() {
    install -d ${D}/etc/evcc
    install -m 0644 ${S}/DefaultDBC.dbc ${D}/etc/evcc/DefaultDBC.dbc
    install -m 0644 ${S}/can_dbc_defines.h ${D}/etc/evcc/can_dbc_defines.h

    install -d ${STAGING_DIR_TARGET}${libdir}/lib_myprovider
    install -m 0755 ${S}/DefaultDBC.dbc ${STAGING_DIR_TARGET}${libdir}/lib_myprovider/DefaultDBC.dbc
    install -m 0755 ${S}/can_dbc_defines.h ${STAGING_DIR_TARGET}${libdir}/lib_myprovider/can_dbc_defines.h
}

RDEPENDS_${PN} += "python3 python3-pip"

FILES_${PN} = "/etc/evcc/DefaultDBC.dbc \
               /etc/evcc/can_dbc_defines.h"

This properly creates the files and puts them into /dbc-creator/1.0+gitrAUTOINC+2966a1ada9-r0/recipe-sysroot/usr/lib/lib_myprovider. This means my producer is working as expected.
In my mainapplication recipe I have
DEPENDS += "libsocketcan boost dbcppp dbc-creator"

do_fetch[depends] += "dbc-creator:do_populate_sysroot"

do_compile_prepend() {
    echo "STAGING_DIR_TARGET: ${STAGING_DIR_TARGET}"
    echo "Checking for can_dbc_defines.h..."

    if [ ! -f ${STAGING_DIR_TARGET}${libdir}/lib_myprovider/can_dbc_defines.h ]; then
        echo "ERROR: can_dbc_defines.h not found in ${STAGING_DIR_TARGET}${libdir}/lib_myprovider"
        exit 1
    fi

    cp ${STAGING_DIR_TARGET}${libdir}/lib_myprovider/can_dbc_defines.h ${S}/evccapplication/include/comms/CAN

    if [ ! -f ${STAGING_DIR_TARGET}${libdir}/lib_myprovider/DefaultDBC.dbc ]; then
        echo "ERROR: DefaultDBC.dbc not found in ${STAGING_DIR_TARGET}${libdir}/lib_myprovider"
        exit 1
    fi

    # Run md5sum on DefaultDBC.dbc and store the hash in a variable
    HASH=$(md5sum ${STAGING_DIR_TARGET}${libdir}/lib_myprovider/DefaultDBC.dbc | awk '{ print $1 }')

    # Use sed to replace the DEFAULT_MD5_HASH define in dbcppp_parser.h
    sed -i "s/.*#define DEFAULT_MD5_HASH.*\/\/prod/#define DEFAULT_MD5_HASH\t\t\"${HASH}\" \/\/prod/g" ${S}/evccapplication/include/config_parsing/dbcppp_parser.h
}
FILES_${PN} = "${libdir}/lib_myprovider"

From what I have read this should create the lib_myprovider in the recipe-sysroot/usr/lib/ folder of this recipe. However this does not occur. How do I get my files from one recipe into the another?

I vaguely remember that Yocto does not like it when two recipes work on the same files in FILES_${PN}. Apart from that your recipes look fine to me. You're on Dunfell, aren't you?
